# How to Efficiently Comparing User Input with multiple Output Scenario in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

I have looked for a bit, trying to find the answer to my question, but I haven't found anything.

I am programming in Java, and I was wondering if there was an efficient way to take the user's input and compare with a number of possible outputs.

I would then like the program to execute code depending on the Input. I know you are able to do `switch()` `if(){` as well as do `AND` or `OR` in an `if(){` statement.

I am trying to avoid doing an `if(){` statement with a bunch of `}else if{` statement as well as `AND` / `OR`s  in an `if(){` statement.

I was just wondering if a `switch()` would be the way to go, or if there was a more efficient way of doing that.

EDIT: I haven't written anything yet. I was just wondering. If the question is too vague, don't worry. I was just curious. Thanks again!

Thanks,
  ~Rane

Comment: The question is vague and invites conjecture. You could use a "command" look up strategy, where you would maintain a `Map` of valid "commands" (probably in `String`), which link to an implementation of an `interface` which provides a simple "execute" method.  You would then simply take the user input, look the specified "command" in the `Map` and if it exists, execute the `interface` implementation...but this might not meet your needs.  Can you provide a use case or test case?

Comment: Can you provide more context into your idea?  A use case or test case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just lookup values with a string then use a Map like Michael suggested. However, if you want to do something more based on a string, then use a switch statement (as of Java 7).

```
String input = ....;
switch(input) {
case "input1":
  // do stuff
  break;
case "input2":
  // do stuff
}
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map and pre-define your key-value pairs there and try to match the user input with the keys to get an output.

```
String userInput = "input1"; // test
Map<String, String> inputMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

inputMap.put("input1", "output1");
inputMap.put("input2", "output2"); //etc..

String userOutput = (String) inputMap.get(userInput);
```

Ouput will be `output1`. If no match is retrieved, then null is returned.

I hope I understood your need properly.